# Confused about sending email in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello all can anyone please explain what would the `UserName` and `Password` be? I believe that those are asking for my gmail's username and password right? (I'm the one who will always receive emails) I am trying to implement the email service for my contact form. Sorry I'm pretty new to asp.net mvc.

```
public class MailService : IMailService
{
    public string SendMail(string from, string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        var errorMessage = "";
        try
        {
            var msg = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = "myemail@yahoo.com",
                    Password = "password"
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(msg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        return errorMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: getting down vote of something I don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The Username and Password are the ones required by your host. In this case the credentials you need to login at smtp.gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to authenticate using the login information just as if you were setting up an email client to send emails.

[SmtpClient.Credentials Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the credentials used to **authenticate the sender**.
>   ....
>   Some SMTP servers require that the client be authenticated before the server will send e-mail on its behalf.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the gmail username and password.
Remember to create a application specific password and use that instead of the actual gmail password

---

Found the following code in one of my projects:

```
static Task sendMail(IdentityMessage message)
{
    string text = string.Format("Please confirm your account by pasting this link on your browser\'s address bar:\n\n{0}", message.Body);
    string html = "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + message.Body + "\">this link</a><br/>";

    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("id@gmail.com");
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
    msg.Subject = message.Subject;
    msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
    msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", Convert.ToInt32(587));
    System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("id@gmail.com", "gmailpassword");
    smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    return smtpClient.SendMailAsync(msg);
}
```